# creating an array in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

I have a Google Spreadsheet where in a column B names are captured and in column E attendance is captured. Is there any way where I can get a list of people who has attended (Marked as P in Column E) in another sheet or spreadsheet file (using importrange and then applying the formulae?)

Comment: I don't want to add filter and get all participants with Attendance Status P together. I am looking for a way to have a continuous array where names of Participants names who has attended (as per Column E value of "P") will be listed one below other while ignoring participants for whom Column E value is not "P".

Comment: You can do with importrange and query, but the easy way is you use filter formula

Comment: You can use filter like this, =filter(oldsheet!A:E, oldsheet!E:E="P")

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to any Google Spreadsheet as a csv file, then you can use this data in you faviourite scripting language to create an array.

Comment: Thank you Toby. It is true, but the requirement or most feasible option I am looking is not to involve any other tool apart from Google Spreadsheets as the resulting sheet will be shared with someone else who will work on it and they do not have resources of knowledge about how to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions like `VLOOKUP`:

> Vertical lookup. Searches down the first column of a range for a key and returns the value of a specified cell in the row found."

`VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])`

See: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en

For you task it might just be a simple VLOOKUP looking at the range B to E and setting index to return B value while seaching for a specific event.

To return multiple values using Vlookup in Google Sheets you can add `ARRAYFORMULA`.

> Enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with arrays

See: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en

Now you can chain the formulas, e.g. `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(condition))`.

For more complex tasks you can use `QUERY`:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343

Comment: I am a novice so I may be wrong but isn't VLOOKUP will return first value matching the search_key?

Answer (score 0):

after you connect your sheets try:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("id_here"; "sheetname_here!B:E"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("id_here"; "sheetname_here!E:E")="P")
```

or:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("id_here"; "sheetname_here!B:E")}; 
 "select Col1 where Col4='P'", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot!!! Filter() worked like a miracle, Query not so much... I must have done something wrong there but in any ways, thanks a lot... it solved the issue